# Unable to signup Instagram using JS (Age verfication page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, instagram, html-select

I passed the first page of signup and now am on the age verification page of **Instagram signup page**

[Image of Instagram Signup page where I got stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxIbi.png)

I want to pass this page using JS

The code I tried is :-

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".h144Z  ");

x[0].selectedIndex = 0
x[1].selectedIndex = 0
x[2].selectedIndex = 22
```

And the result I get is :-

[Image of output from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS52D.jpg)

But even after setting these value , I didn't get the next button ..

I tried the next button by removing the disable option and The button then is active but is not responding and when I click on any select field after filling it using JS then those values get reset back automatically and are not allowing me to continue using JS .

If I try to fill things normally mean by clicking with mouse and selecting values then I receive the next button with active response but I am not getting it using JS.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: What business would you have trying to “automate” this in the first place, that can hardly have any allowed, non-spammy application.

Comment: No , I am not doing this for any business ..
I am a new learner and this is my first question I asked .
My motive is just to learn from this ..
I tried this system on other websites and this works but on Instagram .. It didn't work .

I just want to solve this problem and learn how can I do this on Instagram also ..

Thank you for replying  : )

Comment: The previous comment may give you your answer .. : )

Comment: Did you know the answer to this question ?

Comment: I would suggest you to provide more code so that it would be easier to see what you have tried and answer your question.